# Is ReadyToRun tightly bound to a linux distro?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, compilation

Can I create my R2R assemblies on my Ubuntu-on-WSL2 and run them on Amazon Linux 2 (can't have that one on WSL2) ?

Or I really need to do the ReadyToRun publishing on "Amazon Linux 2" ?